# Estimating errors using Taylor's theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Estimate the error in using the Taylor polynomial of degree $1$ about $x=0$ to compute $\sin(0.1)$

Let $f(x) = \sin x$

Degree $1 \implies n = 1$

$\sin x$ is $C^\infty$ so is certainly n + 1 times differentiable on $(a - r, a + r)$. So the theorem's hypothesis applies.

I'm not sure how to subsitute into the formula ie. I don't see how to assign $a$ and $b$ (from the formula). Could someone also explain what $r$ in the interval refers to or is it just a generic $r$ so that the interval is symmetrical.

Sorry I couldn't include the theorem but LaTeX was being uncooperative and the resulting formula was more confusing than helpful

Comment: The error function is the abs(Taylor polynomial of the function - the function) = abs(sinx-x). I have found a nice video from The Organic Chemistry Tutor on YouTube which explains it:https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=lY0LzJXTgeo&t=233s

Answer (score 1):

The degree $1$ taylor polynomial for $\sin(x)$ about $x=0$ is
$$\frac{\sin(0)}{0!} + \frac{\cos(0)}{1!}(x-0) = x$$
So the approximation of $\sin(.1)$ by the Taylor polynomial of degree $1$ is $\approx .1$. Then Taylor's Theorem states
$$R_1 = \frac{-\sin(z)}{2}(.1)^2 = -\frac{\sin(z)}{200}$$
for some $z \in (0,.1)$ where $R_1$ is the remainder. Of course, the hypothesis holds as $\sin(x)$ is infinitely differentiable (which you can prove using induction and showing it is twice differentiable). In general, Taylor's Theorem states

> If a function $f$ is differentiable $n+1$ times in an interval $I$ containing $c$, then, for each $x$ in $I$, there exists a $z$ between $c$ and $x$ such that
> $$f(x) = f(c) + f'(c)(x-c)+\frac{f''(c)}{2}(x-c)^2 + \ldots + \frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}(x-c)^n + R_{n}(x)$$
> where
> $$R_n(x) = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(z)}{(n+1)!}(x-c)^{n+1}$$

Comment: @McCarter Trying to compute the error of $\sin(.1)$ by computing $\sin(.1)-.1$ defeats the purpose of approximating $\sin(.1)$. By using this formula you can put bounds on the error, which was the intention of the formula.